# Pegar o valor do array PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte situação após eu dar um print_r no "$restultado = array(json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))";

```
Array
(
    [0] => {
    "nome_evento": "C\u00edrculo de Mulheres com Arte Biogr\u00e1fica",
    "group-a": [
        {
            "data_ini": "01\/01\/2017",
            "data_fim": "31\/12\/2017",
            "hora_inicio": "14:00",
            "hora_fim": "18:00",
            "somente_semana": "06"
        },
        {
            "data_ini": "01\/09\/2018",
            "data_fim": "30\/09\/2018",
            "hora_inicio": "08:00",
            "hora_fim": "18:00"
        }
    ],
    "data_ini": [
        "01\/01\/2017"
    ],
    "data_fim": [
        "31\/12\/2017"
    ],
    "hora_inicio": [
        "14:00"
    ],
    "hora_fim": [
        "18:00"
    ],
    "somente_semana": [
        "06"
    ],
    "publico_alvo": "Mulheres acima dos 42 anos",
    "ritmo": "12 encontros mensais",
    "realizacao": "",
    "investimento": "",
    "descricao": "Compartilhando o segundo setênio (7 a 14 anos). Mulheres que são capazes de atravessar a urdidura e a trama de suas vidas para descobrir quais fios que partem de lá até aqui. As fantasias, os irmãos e primos brincando na corredeira das águas da chuva, as festas religiosas, as tarefas de casa e os primeiros anos da escola.

Voltar ao cenário da infância nos ajuda a estabelecer um relacionamento adulto com essa pretensa realidade. Os fatos da vida da pessoa são bem menos importantes do que a maneira como nos lembramos deles, o modo como os interiorizamos e somos impulsionados por eles, ou como somos capazes de trabalhar com eles.",
    "resultados": "",
    "objetivos": "",
    "filesize": "",
    "filetype": "",
    "filedim": "",
    "w": "",
    "h": "",
    "salvar": "ok",
    "id_item_atu": "2",
    "x1": "",
    "y1": "",
    "x2": "",
    "y2": ""
}
)
```

Eu precisaria salvar os campos "data_ini", "data_fim", "hora_inicio", "hora_fim" e "somente_semana".
Tentei a tarde toda, mas o que consegui foi pegar a posição 0, com um "print_r($restultado[0])".
É possível fazer um foreach para pegar esses campos?
Esse resultado é do jQuery Repeater, e na documentação, eles pedem para usar um Json (json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))

Comment: Já tentou: $restultado[0]->data_ini ou $restultado[0]['data_ini'] ?

Comment: json_encode é para você formartar o array para o Json. Você pode tentar o json_decode e acessar assim :  $restultado[0]->data_ini

Comment: Acabei de testar. Retorna "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\cliente\painel_ctr\pages\evento_edita.php on line 350".

Comment: Testei assim: $resultado = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); echo $resultado; Ele retorna "{ "nome_evento": "C\u00edrculo de Mulheres com Arte Biogr\u00e1fica", "group-a": [ { "data_ini": "01\/01\/2017", "data_fim": "31\/12\/2017", "hora_inicio": "14:00", "hora_fim": "18:00", "somente_semana": "06" } ], "data_ini": [ "01\/01\/2017" ], "data_fim": [ "31\/12\/2017" ], "hora_inicio": [ "14:00" ], "hora_fim": [ "18:00" ],"... O problema está nessa chave, que não deixa acessar os outros elementos.

Comment: Tenta json_decode ao invés de encode. Tá tudo certo do jeito que vc fez agora mas retorna em JSON pq vc está pedindo isso pro php